# How we can use toggle button for per row in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-togglebutton

I am try to learn jetpack compose, and I have a text row in my screen, I want to use toggle button for per row, but I am not sure, how can I  add toggle button in this project, I know how to add image button, but I am not sure how implement toggle button in here, any idea?

```
 @Composable
fun MainScreen() {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally

        ) {
  
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start) {

            MainRow(
                name = "name1",
                )

            MainRow(
                name = "name2",

                )

            MainRow(
                name = "name3",

                )
            MainRow(
                name = "name4",

                )}}
   
@Composable
fun MainRow(
    name: String,


    ) {
    
    Row(
       
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {


        Text(
            text = name,
            
        )}}
```

**toggle:**

```
  Switch(
            modifier = Modifier.scale(1f),
            checked = checkedState.value,
            onCheckedChange = { checkedState.value = it },
            colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
                checkedThumbColor = Color.Red,
                uncheckedThumbColor = Color.Green,
                checkedTrackColor = Color.Yellow,
                uncheckedTrackColor = Color.Black
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your row as

```
@Composable
private fun MainRow(name:String, change:Boolean, onCheckedChange: (Boolean) -> Unit) {

    Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {

        Switch(
            checked = change,
            onCheckedChange = onCheckedChange,
            colors = SwitchDefaults.colors(
                checkedThumbColor = Color.Red,
                uncheckedThumbColor = Color.Green,
                checkedTrackColor = Color.Yellow,
                uncheckedTrackColor = Color.Black
            )
        )
        
        Text(text = name)
    }
}
```

And use it as

```
    var selected1 by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    MainRow(name = "Row1", change = selected1, onCheckedChange = {
        selected1 = it
    })

   var selected2 by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}
    
    MainRow(name = "Row1", change = selected2, onCheckedChange = {
        selected2 = it
    })
```

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer, but when I click the togger bottom, all buttons open same time for four per four row

Comment: You should create  **State** for each MainRow using `mutableStateOf `. `mutableStateOf ` is like `LiveData` for Compose. Any Composable that reads a `MutableState`  recomposes according to variable `MutableSate` stores.

Comment: I get it tnx so so much :)